# Some (but not all) controller action routes return 404 on staging server

Tags: controller, multi-environment, 404, modules

I've created a module for a project that has several actions, all of which are called through AJAX. Each is a post request that sends over any required params plus the CSRF token using the method described here: https://craftcms.com/guides/enabling-csrf-protection#updating-your-javascript

On localhost, everything works correctly. On the staging server, some work correctly but others return a 404 error. Specifically, the response gives "Template not found: actions/module-name/location/geocode-inputs".

web.log doesn't look to be throwing any errors, and I'm not sure where else to look. Any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out, it was bad error handling on my part.

If the service you're calling returns NULL, this will appear in the network tab as a 404.